# factory/service data being overwritten by next call to API endpoint

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

Im having issues with populating 2 highcharts graphs on a single page using a factory or service endpoint to grab my data automatically. Ive setup a directive which is working fine, i can see the element being bound and 2 charts appearing, the issue is that the factory/service are overwriting their previous data with a new set of data of the last called api. So i can see 2 charts but only 1 has been graphed correctly, the other is blank because its getting blank data (or identical data). Ive got separate controllers, im not sure why this factory/service is bleeding from one to another.

Controller:

```
.controller('getSalesByDay', ['$scope', 'liveStats', function($scope, liveStats){

    var promise = liveStats.getLiveStats({api_path: 'salebydayorhour'});
    promise.then(function (saledata){
        $scope.saleData = saledata.data.count
        $scope.axisInfo = {
            categories: saledata.data.date
        }
    })

}])

.controller('getForeCastByDay', ['$scope', 'getForeCastByDay', function($scope, getForeCastByDay) {



    $scope.getForecastByDay = getForecastByDay.query({api_path: 'getforecastdata'})
        .$promise.then(function (forecast) {

            $scope.forecastData = forecast.count;
            $scope.axisInfo = {
                categories: forecast.date
            }
        });
    }])
```

Factory/Service:

```
.service('liveStats', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(API_PATH+'live_stats/salesbyday', {api_path: '@api_path'})
    .then(function (data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    this.getLiveStats = function () {
        return deferred.promise;
    }

}])

.factory('getLiveStats', ['$resource', function($resource) {

        return $resource(API_PATH+'live_stats/:api_path', {api_path: '@api_path'},
        {
            query: {
                isArray: false
            }
        }
    );

}])
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="getSalesByDay">
    <div ng-if="salesData">
        <datachart data="salesData" axis="axisInfo"></datachart>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="getForecastByDay">
    <div ng-if="forecastData">
        <datachart "data="forecastData" axis="axisInfo"></datachart>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Ive tried both passing the promise and defer methods, ive tried .then, i cant seem to work out how to hit a specific endpoint (like how ive got it in my factory as that is customized with a api_path configuration) and request 2 json blobs of data to populate 2 independent graphs on a single page.

Any help would be fantastic, been stuck on this for a while now, searched far and wide but i think im missing something key.

Note: I have changed scope/controller names as this is a private project that i dont want names released for (if anyone spots a spelling mistake or variable's that dont match, all the code works fine on this side).

Answer (score 1):

The `$http` service returns a promise. No need to create one with `$q`.

Factory/Service:

```
.service('liveStats', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    this.getLiveStats = function (config) {
        return $http.get(API_PATH+'live_stats/salesbyday',config);
    }
}])
```

Comment: You can also remove the injection to `$q` since it's not relevant.

Comment: The endpoints are being reached correctly by passing in the config to the function but im still getting only 1 endpoint return data and not both at the same time to separate controllers using the same service. The forecast endpoint is overwriting the salesbyday endpoint.

Comment: still havent solved this issue, would really appreciate some more help, @georgeawg was helpful but im not getting the data separated as intended.